# Replace URL Character Encodings In Windows Filenames (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, urlencode, batch-rename

I am trying to replace [URL encodings](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) (e.g. `%20` as a placeholder for a space) with their corresponding ASCII values in *all* filenames in a Windows folder and its subfolders.

If have a simple `.bat` file that can accomplish this, but it has limitations:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern0=%%20"
Set "Replace0= "

Set "Pattern1=%%27"
Set "Replace1='"

Set "Pattern2=%%28"
Set "Replace2=("

Set "Pattern3=%%29"
Set "Replace3=)"

Set "Pattern4=%%5B"
Set "Replace4={"

Set "Pattern5=%%5D"
Set "Replace5=}"

For %%# in ("D:\Dropbox\Music\*.mp3") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern0%=%Replace0%!"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern3%=%Replace3%!"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern4%=%Replace4%!"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern5%=%Replace5%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

There are two major limitations I'd like to fix:

1. It only checks the `..\Music\` folder root. I'd like it to look at
   files in subdirectories, too.
2. It exits the `For` loop as soon as one of the renames are executed
   (all `%20`'s replaced first pass, for example, but nothing else).

And *surely* there is a better way to specify the encodings and their replacements (rather than variable pairs for each), but that's a nice-to-have feature.

These encodings always take the form `%XX`, where X are hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To solve directory recursive search, you could use `dir /s /b` instead

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir /s /b "D:\Dropbox\Music\*.mp3"') Do (
...
)
```

2. Do not rename the file any time, only after all replacements

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir /s /b "D:\Dropbox\Music\*.mp3"') Do (
   set "file=%%~#"
   set "file="!File:%%20= !"
   set "file="!File:%%28=(!"
   ...
   move "%%~#" "!file!"
)
```

I'm using move here, because it works with full pathnames, too

3. To solve problems with exclamation marks in filenames/paths, you need to toggle delayed expansion

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir /s /b "D:\Dropbox\Music\*.mp3"') Do (
   set "file=%%~#"

   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "file="!File:%%20= !"
   set "file="!File:%%28=(!"
   ...
   move "%%~#" "!file!"
   endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It looks like the only step left to me is to fill in the specific renames manually, y/n? E.g. next line would (presumably) be `set "file="!File:%%29=)!"` -- and so forth?

If that's true, I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid one row of code for any/every ASCII encoding (originating from URL encodes)? Again, we know the values to match are always in the format `%HH` where H = a hexadecimal char.

Comment: @DerekClark Yes, only add the missing replacements. You could also search for the percent sign and fetch the next two characters and convert them, BUT that is not trivial

Comment: Noted, and thank you once again. I'm familiar with the conventions of regular expressions, but aware that knowledge may not transfer well when dealing with Windows scripts